# Finding a line that is tangent to a given curve

Tags: calculus

Find the value of $c$ such that the line $y = \frac{5}{6}x + \frac{15}{2}$ is tangent to the curve $y = c \sqrt{x}$ .

I'm having a lot of  trouble solving this problem. Is there anyone who could please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there must be a point $x$ at which

(1) the $y$ values on the line and curve are equal;

(2) the gradients of line and curve are equal.

Working out the details will give you two equations in $c$ and $x$; eliminating $x$ will give two values of $c$; but only one of them makes sense for this problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you offer a little bit more of an explanation? Haha sorry, this stuff just confuses me.

Comment: Draw a pair of axes; draw any curve you like (doesn't have to be the one in your question); draw any tangent to the curve; then I think you will see why (1) and (2) have to be true.

Comment: How do I deal with the C though?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question.

Comment: Could you work the problem out halfway so I could take it from there?

Comment: Can you find the gradient of the line from its equation?  Can you find the gradient of the curve at a point $x$?

Answer (score 1):

We are given the line $y_1={\frac5 6}x+\frac{15}{2}$ and the curve $y_2=c\sqrt{x}$ .
Since they are tangent to each other, we know that $y_1 = y_2$ and $y_1' = y_2'$.
Using these facts, we obtain $\frac{5} {6}x+\frac{15}{2} = c\sqrt{x}$ and $\frac{5}{6} = \frac{c}{2\sqrt{x}}$, respectively. Simplifying the second equation gives us, $x=\frac{9}{5}c^2$. Substitute *x* into the first equation, we obtain $c=\pm 5$. Substitute *c* into equation 2, both give us $x=9$. Verifying the first equation, we confirm that $c=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw an equation for the $x$ value of the contact point by putting the $y$ values equal to each other. Try to express it as a quadratic equation. If the line is a tangent line, the equation should have only one root. Using this information you can compute $c$.

Answer (score 0):

You need the slope of the line and curve to be equal, for starters.  The slope of the line is $\frac{5}{6}$ and the slope of your function is
$$y'=\frac{c}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

We need these to be equal, so when does
$$\frac{5}{6}=\frac{c}{2\sqrt{x}}?$$

That's part of the problem.  That's one equation with two unknowns, so we need one more equation, can you think of it? (Hint: Not only do the slopes have to be equal at $x$, but the function values have to be, as well).